# Canvas - Firefox Issue

Tags: jquery, firefox, canvas

Working on a project of mine, I just realized that I am having trouble with displaying text rendered by an image using `canvas` and `JQuery`.

Code:

```
//get values
        var current = $(".activeText a div").attr('id');

        //get font family
        var fFamily = $(".activeText a .fontType-cont").val();

        // default remove old
        $(".customize-Container #draggable").remove();
        //create a canvas for image converting

        $(".customize-Container").append("<div id='draggable'><canvas id='"+current+"'></canvas></div>");
        //create canvas

        var canvas = document.getElementById(current),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = document.createElement('img');
        //draw it
        img.onload = drawSmall;
        img.src = $(".activeGColor").find('img').attr('src');

        function drawSmall() {
            var text = $("#fontEnter").val();
            //define new font size
            howMuch = startFontSize - howMuch;
            //define var with new font size
            startFontSize = howMuch;
            //define text font size and family
            ctx.font = howMuch + 'px ' + fFamily;
            //fill with the text
            ctx.fillText(text, 10, 100);
            //draw text
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 20, 500, 100);
        }
```

Here is what happens, this is a function inside a re sizer.  This particular function decreases the text size.  Now what happens is before I am using similar code to display the text and that works perfect.  Now once this function is selected the text disappears and does not finish its process, leaving the canvas blank.

I've used `alert()` to see where it stops and it seems to stop on the `img.onload = drawSmall;` without entering the `drawSmall()` function.

This works perfect in Chrome an IE (<-- wow right?)  Let me know your suggestions.

David

UPDATE:

Just realized that Firefox is telling me this:

`[14:08:46.456] ReferenceError: drawSmall is not defined @ ../wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/jquery-latest.min.js:297`

Comment: Yes, amazingly, IE is currently better than Firefox. This is because Firefox has sucked since Version 4, and I really wish they'd get their arses in gear. Same with Chrome, to a lesser extent. It took them four years to fix a bug I reported, and it took ten minutes of work to actually fix it...

Comment: @Kolink nothing compares to Chrome...anyways, any idea?

Comment: I beg to differ. Chrome still doesn't support the unprefixed versions of `linear-gradient`, `transition`, `transform`, `animation` and so on, resulting in a lot of "Chrome-specific" code... IE10, however, completely skipped the prefix stage on a lot of these, supporting the right version off the bat.

Comment: @Kolink I can use those attributes just fine?

Comment: Well, looks like `transition` and `linear-gradient` were added in Chrome 26. I withdraw my comments about those ones. However, `transform` and `animation` still require prefixes. Also, Chrome is unable to animate gradients.

Comment: I use gradients just fine also lol

Comment: You can't animate them though.

Comment: JQuery?.....   anyways so do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Nope, sorry. If I did I'd answer. And jQuery is not a valid substitute for the browser not supporting something that all the other browsers (even IE!) do.

Answer (score 1):

Funny the way FireFox works.  This is what needed to happen:

```
function drawSmall() {
      ...
}
//get values
var current = $(".activeText a div").attr('id');
var text = $("#fontEnter").val();
//get font family

..the rest
```

`function drawSmall()` needed to be `declared before` the canvas was being declared.